# How to develop (run and debug) modules in Odoo v11 on Visual Studio Code in Ubuntu?

Tags: python, debugging, visual-studio-code, odoo, odoo-11

Is it possible to run and debug Odoo on Visual Studio Code? If yes please share me the configuration.

> [**Visual Studio Code**](https://code.visualstudio.com/) is a source code editor developed by Microsoft for Windows, Linux and macOS. It includes support for debugging, embedded Git control, syntax highlighting, intelligent code completion, snippets, and code refactoring. It is free and open-source, although the official download is under a proprietary license.

Comment: Did you try pycharm man it's greate IDE for python

Comment: Yes, currently i am using pycharm but i am tired of the trial version.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I know I'm a bit late but I have managed to work with Odoo 11.

My installation path is "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 11.0\server"

Now open the vs code and goto Workspace settings and paste this:

```
{
"python.pythonPath": "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Odoo 11.0\\python\\python.exe",
"python.linting.pylintEnabled": false,
// use this so the autocompleate/goto definition will work with python extension
"python.autoComplete.extraPaths": [
    "${workspaceRoot}/odoo/addons",
    "${workspaceRoot}/odoo",
    "${workspaceRoot}/odoo/openerp/addons"
],
//"python.linting.pylintPath": "optional: path to python use if you have environment path",
"python.linting.enabled": false,
//load the pylint_odoo
"python.linting.pylintArgs": [
    "--load-plugins",
    "pylint_odoo"
],
"python.formatting.provider": "yapf",
//"python.formatting.yapfPath": "optional: path to python use if you have environment path",
// "python.linting.pep8Path": "optional: path to python use if you have environment path",
"python.linting.pep8Enabled": true,
// add this auto-save option so the pylint will sow errors while editing otherwise
//it will only show the errors on file save
"files.autoSave": "afterDelay",
"files.autoSaveDelay": 500,
// The following will hide the compiled file in the editor/ add other file to hide them from editor
"files.exclude": {
    "**/*.pyc": true
}
```

}

save it and open the code folder in vs "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 11.0\server\odoo"

then goto debugging setting and a new configuration file and paste below code:

```
{
// Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
// Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
// For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
"version": "0.2.0",
"configurations": [
    {
        "name": "Python: Odoo",
        "type": "python",
        "request": "launch",
        "stopOnEntry": false,
        "pythonPath": "${config:python.pythonPath}",
        "console": "externalTerminal",
        "program": "${workspaceRoot}\\..\\odoo-bin",
        "args": [
            "--config=${workspaceRoot}\\..\\odoo.conf",
        ],
        "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}",
        "env": {},
        "envFile": "${workspaceRoot}/.env",
        "debugOptions": [
            "RedirectOutput"
        ]
    }
]
```

}

and just hit the run button. remember vs code might give you some warning press ignore button and wait for the console to open and you are done. enjoy debugging and coding.

Don't forget to stop the **Odoo service** from window services.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can even debug Odoo with VSCode:

First, you need to install the [**Python Extension**](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-python.python) within VSCode.

Add the folder where Odoo is installed to the current project. You can use the functionality [**Multiroot Workspaces**](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/multi-root-workspaces). I think it is convenient in this case: open your project modules in one folder, and Odoo in other folder

Then, if you want to start debugging you just need to click on the Debug button and click on the wheel on the top of the sidebar. The file `launch.json` will open and you just need to add this element to the bottom.

```js
{
    "name": "Python: Odoo",
    "type": "python",
    "request": "launch",
    "stopOnEntry": false,
    "pythonPath": "${config:python.pythonPath}",
    "console": "externalTerminal",
    "program": "${workspaceRoot}/odoo_path/odoo.py",
    "args": [
        "--config=/odoo_config_path/.odoo_8.conf",
    ],
    "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}",
    "env": {},
    "envFile": "${workspaceRoot}/.env",
    "debugOptions": [
        "RedirectOutput"
    ]
}
```

Once it is added you already can run Odoo under VSCode. For more information about the launch configurations [click here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/debugging#_launch-configurations)

Now you can create breakpoint as usual. You can use the debugger console as well. And if you use the property: `"console": "externalTerminal"` as I did, you can show the log in an external console at the same time

[image]

**Note**: If you only want to run odoo you can use the integrated console in VSCode

**Note 2**: I recommend to install [the Odoo Snippets extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=jeffery9.odoo-snippets) as well.

Comment: Thank you for you quick response, did you try it for odoo version 11?

Comment: I have tried with the version 8 and it is working. I hope it will work with the rest of versions

Comment: I have updated the answer. Actually I have added the odoo folder to the current project and I use relative path with the `${workspaceRoot}`

Comment: For some reason it is not working for me, it says module odoo not found.

Comment: Have you put the rigth addons path in the config file? Keep in mind that you shoud use the `odoo-bin` file instead of `odoo.py` in the 11 version. Anyway I have tried with the 8th version. I will try with the 11 version later if I have time

Comment: Did you try it?

Comment: I didn't have time sorry. I will let you know when I try it

Comment: I have tried with the versions 10 and 11 and it works! @BinyamAssefa Are you using the right python version? Make sure you are using python3 for Odoo 11. You can go to the `odoo-bin` file and change the header to force the python version you want to use `#!/usr/bin/python3`

Comment: I did everything you said, still no luck. By the way i am using lubuntu os.

Comment: Uhm are you using the right python version within VSCode? Take a look at my screenshot, at the status bar. You should see the Python 3 version. You can change it by clicking on it. Where do you get the `"module odoo not found"` message, on the external terminal?

Comment: What is the right python version? I am using python 3.6(64 bit)

Comment: OK, the version is right for Odoo 11. I don´t know why it is not working then :/

Answer (score 0):

I want to add updated answer and so I am sharing simple `launch.json` script I am using. This script assume odoo is in project folder.

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Odoo",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}/odoo-bin",
            "console": "integratedTerminal",
            "args": [
                "--addons-path",
                "addons,mymodules",
            ],
        }
    ]
}
```

vscode version: 1.39.2 (September 2019)

odoo version: 11

about `launch.json`: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/debugging#_launch-configurations

Answer (score 0):

My settings - Odoo 12, Visual Studio Code 1.40.0, Linux

Building on Adeel Rizvi's post - thanks a lot! Updated for Linux and for newer VSCode.

I spent better part of the day to make it work. I use a multi-instance setup for Odoo, which didn't help at all.

For debugging, I needed to sort out the permissions hick-ups, so I decided to run the debugging instance as a current user. In the next commands, always replace `myuser` by your actual user name. Using my `odoo70` user was a no-go, as it couldn't access the vscode stuff in my home folder, including the debugger.

I copied the Odoo stuff to `/opt/odoo70l`, did `sudo chown -R myuser:users /opt/odoo70l` and created a new postgres user `sudo su - postgres -c "createuser --createdb --username postgres --no-createrole --no-superuser --no-password myuser"` to keep being able to use peer authentication. That also required changing the database user to `myuser` in the config file - for me `/opt/odoo70l/odoo70l.conf`. (Note that it will make the previous databases inaccessible for the debugging instance - either change their owner, or export and import under the new user.) I also commented out the logfile there so it would print logs directly to the terminal.

I have my workspace in `/opt/odoo-dev/` and its subfolders contain projects with modules I work on. I use multi-root workspace to be able to also peek into the base Odoo code.

My workspace options (`/opt/odoo-dev/workspace-name.code-workspace`):

(Each of my Odoo instances have their own python venv - if you don't use that, remember to edit `python.pythonPath` to `/usr/bin/python3` or wherever your `which python3` points to.)

```
{
    "folders": [
        {
            "path": "."
        },
        {
            "path": "/opt/odoo70l"
        },
    ],
    "settings": {
        "python.pythonPath": "/opt/odoo70l/odoo-venv/bin/python3",
        "python.linting.pylintEnabled": false,
        // use this so the autocompleate/goto definition will work with python extension
        "python.autoComplete.extraPaths": [
            "/opt/odoo70l/odoo/addons",
            "/opt/odoo70l/odoo",
            "/opt/odoo70l/odoo/odoo/addons"
        ],
        //"python.linting.pylintPath": "optional: path to python use if you have environment path",
        "python.linting.enabled": false,
        //load the pylint_odoo
        "python.linting.pylintArgs": [
            "--load-plugins",
            "pylint_odoo"
        ],
        "python.formatting.provider": "yapf",
        //"python.formatting.yapfPath": "optional: path to python use if you have environment path",
        // "python.linting.pep8Path": "optional: path to python use if you have environment path",
        "python.linting.pep8Enabled": true,
        // add this auto-save option so the pylint will sow errors while editing otherwise
        //it will only show the errors on file save
        "files.autoSave": "afterDelay",
        "files.autoSaveDelay": 500,
        // The following will hide the compiled file in the editor/ add other file to hide them from editor
        "files.exclude": {
            "**/*.pyc": true
        }
    },
}
```

My `/opt/odoo-dev/.vscode/launch.json` (only the first block is important, rest is left there from default VSCode configuration in case you want to do other Python debugging as well):

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Python: Odoo 12 myuser",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "stopOnEntry": false,
            "pythonPath": "${config:python.pythonPath}",
            "console": "externalTerminal",
            "program": "/opt/odoo70l/odoo/odoo-bin",
            "args": [
                "--config=/opt/odoo70l/odoo70l.conf",
            ],
            "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}",
            "env": {},
            "envFile": "${workspaceRoot}/.env",
        },
        {
            "name": "Python: Current File (Integrated Terminal)",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${file}",
            "console": "integratedTerminal"
        },
        {
            "name": "Python: Remote Attach",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "attach",
            "port": 5678,
            "host": "localhost",
            "pathMappings": [
                {
                    "localRoot": "${workspaceFolder}",
                    "remoteRoot": "."
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "Python: Module",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "module": "enter-your-module-name-here",
            "console": "integratedTerminal"
        },
        {
            "name": "Python: Django",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}/manage.py",
            "console": "integratedTerminal",
            "args": [
                "runserver",
                "--noreload",
                "--nothreading"
            ],
            "django": true
        },
        {
            "name": "Python: Flask",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "module": "flask",
            "env": {
                "FLASK_APP": "app.py"
            },
            "args": [
                "run",
                "--no-debugger",
                "--no-reload"
            ],
            "jinja": true
        },
        {
            "name": "Python: Current File (External Terminal)",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${file}",
            "console": "externalTerminal"
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Let's say possible,

Odoo official development done with ubuntu operating system.

For odoo 11.0 Most suggest subline or gedit with plugins most great tool for development.

Visula studio in ubuntu
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aY4Rhmv5P_Q

We had build lot odoo code since 2011 till date on gedit with ubuntu. Also `atom` https://atom.io/ is good tool for edting contents.

My special concern with gedit, it take very less memory and give speed.
In case you had large RAM, yes. this visual studio works great.

[image]