# How to debug Odoo application in docker with PyCharm

Tags: docker, pycharm, odoo, pydev, remote-debugging

DockerFile

```
FROM odoo:12.0

# Setup with root
USER root

# Set default user when running the container
USER odoo

# Copy source code to image
COPY ./addons/ /mnt/extra-addons/

EXPOSE 8069
```

---

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3.2'
services:
  odoo:
    build: .
    depends_on:
      - db
    ports:
      - "8069:8069"
    environment:
      - HOST=db
      - USER=odoo
      - PASSWORD=myodoo
      - ENV=test
    entrypoint: ['/entrypoint.sh', '--database=odoo', '--dev=all']
    volumes:
      - ./addons:/mnt/extra-addons
      - ./var:/var/lib/odoo
  db:
    image: postgres:10
    ports:
      - "5433:5432"
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_DB=odoo
      - POSTGRES_USER=odoo
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=myodoo
```

How can I debug Odoo application inside docker with PyCharm?

Comment: I can't answer it cleary but you can give "remote debugging" a try.

Comment: are you using PyCharm Community or Professional? (Professional features a nice docker integration)

also you could give https://github.com/tecnativa/doodba a try (it integrates https://github.com/Kozea/wdb as a debugging tool for python)

Comment: you could read about it there https://stackoverflow.com/a/63758922 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48033323/how-to-develop-run-and-debug-modules-in-odoo-v11-on-visual-studio-code-in-ubun